# Program, that optimizing the process of working with XML files

Tags: excel, xml, vba, edit

Sorry for my bad English :( I have a task - i should write a program in Excel VBA,that will in folder and subfolders find all .xml files, scan them and make changes if it necessary. Then program will save all changed files in the folder with name "Todays date_changed" and all non-changed files just transfer to the folder with name "Today date". In the end program should display message about how many files was changed and non-changed. I've already wrote code, that changed .xml file in the proper condition. Here it is:

```
Sub EditXML()
Dim doc As New DOMDocument
    Const filePath As String = "D:\Test3.xml" 'path to the editing file
    Dim isLoaded As Boolean

    isLoaded = doc.Load(filePath)

    If isLoaded Then
        Dim oAttributes As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNodeList
        Set oAttributes = doc.getElementsByTagName("Operation")
        Dim attr As MSXML2.IXMLDOMAttribute
        Dim node As MSXML2.IXMLDOMElement
        Dim tdate As String
        tdate = Format(Now(), "yyyy-mm-dd")
        For Each node In oAttributes
        If (node.getAttributeNode("Client") Is Nothing) Then
        node.setAttribute "Client", "UL"
        End If
            For Each attr In node.Attributes
                If attr.Name = "Client" Then
                 If attr.Value <> "UL" Then
                    attr.Value = "UL"
                    End If
                ElseIf attr.Name = "Date" Then
                    If attr.Value <> "tdate" Then
                    attr.Value = tdate
                End If
                End If
            Next attr
        Next node
        doc.Save filePath
    End If
End Sub
```

Also i wrote a code, that in theory should pick all .xml files in the selected folder, editing them and then save to specific folder, but it doesn't do anything-it compiles, doing something, but saves nothing. Here it is:

```
Sub EditXML()

   Dim MyFolder As String
   Dim MyFile As String
   Dim oDoc As MSXML2.DOMDocument
   Dim doc As New DOMDocument
On Error Resume Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
.Title = "Choose a folder"
.Show
.AllowMultiSelect = False
   If .SelectedItems.Count = 0 Then
      Exit Sub
   End If
MyFolder = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"
End With
MyFile = Dir(MyFolder & "*.xml")
Do While MyFile <> ""
   oDoc.Load (MyFolder & MyFile) 
Dim oAttributes As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNodeList
        Set oAttributes = doc.getElementsByTagName("Operation")
        Dim attr As MSXML2.IXMLDOMAttribute
        Dim node As MSXML2.IXMLDOMElement
        Dim tdate As String
        tdate = Format(Now(), "yyyy-mm-dd")
        For Each node In oAttributes
        If (node.getAttributeNode("Client") Is Nothing) Then
        node.setAttribute "Client", "UL"
        End If
            For Each attr In node.Attributes
                If attr.Name = "Client" Then
                 If attr.Value <> "UL" Then
                    attr.Value = "UL"
                    End If
                ElseIf attr.Name = "Date" Then
                    If attr.Value <> "tdate" Then
                    attr.Value = tdate
                End If
                End If
            Next attr
        Next node
        doc.Save "D:\Test\Output\*.xml"
MyFile = Dir
Loop
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

So, at conclusion, i asking for help in writing this program, because this is my first try to write something in VBA. I need parts of code, that will scaning for xml in folders and subfolders, editing them as i mentioned up here and saving the to a proper folder (depending on whether they were changed or not), as i describe in the begining and messaging about working. Here is an example of xml files with which i working:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Document>
    <Operations>
        <Operation Date="2018-11-06" Client="UL"/>
        <Operation Date="2018-11-06" Client="UL"/>
        <Operation Date="2018-11-06"/>
    </Operations>
</Document>
```

Thank you very much for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

Wow.  You are trying to do A LOT of things here.  Let's start with a couple items, make sure you get that working, and then build out additional features over time.  For starters, you can edit all XML files in a folder in this way.

```
Sub ReplaceStringInFile()

    Const sSearchString As String = "c:\your_path_here\*.xml"

    Dim sBuf As String
    Dim sTemp As String
    Dim iFileNum As Integer
    Dim sFileName As String
    Dim sFilePath As String


    sFileName = Dir(sSearchString)

    Do While sFileName <> ""

        sFilePath = "c:\temp\" & sFileName  'Get full path to file
        iFileNum = FreeFile
        sTemp = ""  'Clear sTemp

        Open sFilePath For Input As iFileNum

            Do Until EOF(iFileNum)

                Line Input #iFileNum, sBuf
                sTemp = sTemp & sBuf & vbCrLf

            Loop

        Close iFileNum

        sTemp = Replace(sTemp, "THIS", "THAT")

        iFileNum = FreeFile

        Open sFilePath For Output As iFileNum
        Print #iFileNum, sTemp

        Close iFileNum

        sFileName = Dir() 'Get the next file
    Loop
End Sub
```

Now, that goes into a single folder to look for XML files, but you said you want to go through all folders and all sub-folders in a directory, right, so you have a recursively loop through this 'list' of folders.  You can use the code below to do that.

```
Sub loopAllSubFolderSelectStartDirector()

'Another Macro must call LoopAllSubFolders Macro to start to procedure
Call LoopAllSubFolders("C:\your_path_here\")

End Sub

'List all files in sub folders
Sub LoopAllSubFolders(ByVal folderPath As String)

Dim fileName As String
Dim fullFilePath As String
Dim numFolders As Long
Dim folders() As String
Dim i As Long

If Right(folderPath, 1) <> "\" Then folderPath = folderPath & "\"
fileName = Dir(folderPath & "*.*", vbDirectory)

While Len(fileName) <> 0

    If Left(fileName, 1) <> "." Then

        fullFilePath = folderPath & fileName

        If (GetAttr(fullFilePath) And vbDirectory) = vbDirectory Then
            ReDim Preserve folders(0 To numFolders) As String
            folders(numFolders) = fullFilePath
            numFolders = numFolders + 1
        Else
            'Insert the actions to be performed on each file
            'This example will print the full file path to the immediate window
            Debug.Print folderPath & fileName
        End If

    End If

    fileName = Dir()

Wend

For i = 0 To numFolders - 1

    LoopAllSubFolders folders(i)

Next i

End Sub
```